# Uniform Law of Large numbers for non-iid matrices

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $W_i=\frac{\delta_i}{\pi_i} S^\prime_i(y_i,\vec\theta)$, where $\delta_i$ is iid Bernoulli r.v, $y_i$ is fixed variable and $\vec \theta$ is a vector of parameters. $S^\prime_i(y_i,\vec\theta)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\vec \theta}S_i(y_i,\vec\theta)$. Suppose the vector
$$ S_i(y_i,x_i,\vec\theta) = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
y_i-\theta_1 &\\(y_i-\theta_1)^2-\theta^2_2
 \end{bmatrix}$$
then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec \theta} S_{i}(y_i,\vec \theta) \text{ will be a matrix of  order } 2 \times 2 \text{ of fixed quantities }.$$ Now $W_i$ is independent but non-identical random matrices because $E(W_i) = E(\delta_i/\pi_i) S^\prime_{i} (y_i,\vec \theta)=S^\prime_{i}(y_i,\vec \theta)$ since $E(\frac{\delta_i}{\pi_i}|\pi_i)=1$ and $y's$ are fixed. I need to show that 
$$
S_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} W_i \text{ convergence in probability to } E(S_N) \text{uniformly}.
$$
Any quick help would be greatly appreciated.